# Need to update field value in HTML using span ID

Tags: jquery

I have HTML java code below...

```
<span id="total">
   <fmt:formatNumber value='${totalValue}' type="currency" maxFractionDigits="2"                         minFractionDigits="2"/>
</span>
```

and i need to update some value to `${totalValue}` in javascript method after doing some calculations.

Tried something like `$('#total').set('${totalValue}', 'newValue');`

But not working . please suggest

Comment: How about: `$("[value='${totalValue}']").val(newValue);` ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to select an xml node that is namespaced, you will have to escape the `:`.

```
$('#total').find('fmt\\:formatNumber').attr('value', 'newValue');
```

Comment: What is printed in the console if you do `console.log($('#total'));` and `console.log($('#total').find('fmt\\:formatNumber'));`?  Also, what version of jQuery are you using?  This worked for me with version 1.8.2.

Comment: @user2088411 For both of your console statements?  That means it can't find anything with the id of `total`.  Check your HTML to be sure that you have something with the id of `total`.  Again, what version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the import
 <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
This is the reason the html is showing tags instead of the renderer value of them.